# How is the Cantor set Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, cantor-set

For a proof I am working on, I assume the Cantor set is Hausdorff because that's what I recall from Analysis. However, now that I think about it, I don't know what an open subset of the Cantor set looks like. So how would I go about showing the Cantor set is Hausdorff?

Comment: Do you know that a subspace of a Hausdorff space is Hausdorff?

Comment: @EricWofsey have zero topological background, so I didn't know that! So $[0,1]$ is hausdorff because for any x<y I can choose (0,x) and (y,1)?

Comment: open set in $C$ are of the form $C\cap U$, where $U$ is open in $\mathbb R$. This is the definition of subspace topology.

Comment: @Craig That's not quite right - $x\not\in (0, x)$ and $y\not\in (y, 1)$. But you're not far off . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber Bah of course...So, how about $[0,1]$ is hausdorff because for any x<y, where $|x-y|<\epsilon$, I can choose U={p such that $|x-p|< \epsilon/2$ }and V={p such that $|p-y|< \epsilon/2 $}.

Comment: @Craig this doesn't work either. If you choose $x=1/3$, $y=2/3$ then you're basically talking about the intervals $(0,2/3)$ and $(1/3,1)$ which are not disjoint

Comment: @mathers101 Oh, from what I understand, if x=1/3 and y=2/3, then what I have would give U=(1/6,1/2) and V=(1/2,5/6), just two balls around x and y barely missing each other.

Comment: @Craig I must have missed the $\epsilon/2$, I thought that was just an $\epsilon$. Yeah you're good. The only problem now is if you have something like $x=1/6$, $y=5/6$, then your intervals go out of the domain $[0,1]$.

Comment: @mathers101 Ah, I see, I'll just consider C as a subspace of R and call it a day for now, I have to move on with my actual homework! Thx for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by "Cantor set" you mean the usual Cantor set, which is a subset of the unit interval $[0, 1]$ - in particular, the Cantor set is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

If I have a set $X$ with a topology $\tau$, then subsets of $X$ can be given the "subspace" topology: if $S\subseteq X$, an open subset of $S$ in the subspace topology is a set of the form $S\cap U$, where $U$ is an open subset of $X$ in the sense of $\tau$. So the natural topology on the Cantor set - indeed, the one which is used by default - is the subspace topology coming from $\mathbb{R}$.

For your problem, you don't really need a full description of the topology on the Cantor set- you just need to show that it's Hausdorff. This turns out to be straightforward: you already (presumably) know that $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff; can you show that a subset of a Hausdorff space (with the subspace topology) is Hausdorff?

---

EXERCISE: there is a natural way to assign to each $x$ in the Cantor set, an infinite sequence of zeroes and ones. There is a nice description of the topology on the Cantor set, in terms of these sequences - can you find it?